# display data returned from a javascript/Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This issue is with jquery.

I have the the following function

```
$('#admin_id').html(getPartnerName(i, data.admin_id));
```

And the function getPartnerName is below

```
function getPartnerName(i, partner_id) {
$.getJSON( '../index.php', 'r=someName&id=1', function(data) {

    return data.admin_name;

});

}
```

I want to print the admin_name returned by json and display it in td with id #admin_id

My code is working fine by not able to display the names.

please help me out to know where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON( '../index.php', 'r=someName&id=1', function(data) {
   $('#admin_id').html(data.admin_name);
});
```

Because the ajax call is asynchronous, you need to provide a callback that is in control of the result parsing; you cannot just return it like from a normal function.

Comment: This i tried before and it worked. But i feel its like calling $('#admin_id').html() function twice.

And because of this I am not able to sort it using tablesorter plugin

Comment: You don't have to call it the first time any more. And for the plugin, maybe you could reinitialize it after you populate the html.  Trust me, even if it might feel complicated, it's the right way to do it... javascript relies much on callbacks and asynchronous functions.

Comment: $.getJSON( '../index.php', 'r=someName&id=1', function(data) {


$('#admin_id').html(data.admin_name);


}).success(function() { $("#tab").trigger("update"); });

I used this and it worked. Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a variable to the function and call the variable inside html()

Ex:

```
var output = function getPartnerName(i, partner_id) {
$.getJSON( '../index.php', 'r=someName&id=1', function(data) {

    return data.admin_name;

});

}

$('#admin_id').html(output);
```

hope this is what you were looking for... :)

Comment: This did not work. :( But anyways i found the answer :)

$.getJSON( '../index.php', 'r=someName&id=1', function(data) {

$('#admin_id').html(data.admin_name);

}).success(function() { $("#tab").trigger("update"); });
I used the success func of getJson and updated my tablesorter table